# Image transition effect on single page

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-7.1, transition

In my application I have a image on UI and when user swipe on a image, I update the "image.Source" property. So the image get updated, but I want to show an animation same as windows phone picture hub has.I seen different tutorial on internet but they are about transitions between different pages. I just want to show transition effect without leaving this page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to a photo gallery like application? I attempted to make one not too long ago, based on some parts of the [tutorial here](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2012/06/06/a-gesture-driven-windows-phone-to-do-application.html)

Essentially, you could use the GestureListener service that comes as part of the windows phone toolkit. There are several other ways of doing this but this is one the approaches I took (in the end, I got a Telerik controls toolkit and used their image gallery control).

1. Create a border element in XAML
2. Set the background image to your first image in the gallery
3. Add a gesture listener defining events for the drag started, drag delta and drag completed events

   ```
   <Border x:Name="imgContainer" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="500" Width="480">
   <Border.Background>
   <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding CurrentPhotoSource}"></ImageBrush>
   </Border.Background>
   <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
   <toolkit:GestureListener
   DragStarted="GestureDragStarted"
   DragDelta="GestureDragDelta"
   DragCompleted="GestureDragCompleted"/>
   </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
   </Border>


   private void GestureDragStarted(object sender, DragStartedGestureEventArgs e)
   {
       //initialize the drag
      var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
      fe.SetHorizontalOffset(0);  
   }



   private void GestureDragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaGestureEventArgs e)
   {
       // handle the drag to offset the element
       var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;
       double offset = fe.GetHorizontalOffset().Value + e.HorizontalChange;
       fe.SetHorizontalOffset(offset);
   }



   private void GestureDragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedGestureEventArgs e)
   {
       var fe = sender as FrameworkElement;

       var trans = fe.GetHorizontalOffset().Transform;

       trans.Animate(trans.X, 0, TranslateTransform.XProperty, 300, 0, new BounceEase()
       {
           Bounciness = 25,
           Bounces = 10
       });

       if (e.HorizontalChange <= 0)
       {
           //This is where you set the next image in the gallery.
           //e.g 
           // imgContainer.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("your image url"))
           //this.ViewModel.SetNext();
       }
       else
       {
           //This is where you set the previous image in the gallery
           //this.ViewModel.SetPrevious();
       }   
   }
   ```

Extension methods for animation, this is assigning values to Tags, not the best approach especially if you are using mvvm, but it's a working sample to get you started.

```
 public static class Felements
{
    public static void SetHorizontalOffset(this FrameworkElement fe, double offset)
    {
        var trans = new TranslateTransform()
        {
            X = offset
        };
        fe.RenderTransform = trans;

        fe.Tag = new Offset()
        {
            Value = offset,
            Transform = trans
        };
    }

    public static Offset GetHorizontalOffset(this FrameworkElement fe)
    {
        return fe.Tag == null ? new Offset() : (Offset)fe.Tag;
    }

    public struct Offset
    {
        public double Value { get; set; }
        public TranslateTransform Transform { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Animate(this DependencyObject target, double from, double to,
                      object propertyPath, int duration, int startTime,
                      IEasingFunction easing = null, Action completed = null)
    {
        if (easing == null)
        {
            easing = new SineEase();
        }

        var db = new DoubleAnimation();
        db.To = to;
        db.From = from;
        db.EasingFunction = easing;
        db.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(duration);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(db, target);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(db, new PropertyPath(propertyPath));

        var sb = new Storyboard();
        sb.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(startTime);

        if (completed != null)
        {
            sb.Completed += (s, e) => completed();
        }

        sb.Children.Add(db);
        sb.Begin();
    }
}
```